# How does the assumption that the distribution must be fully specified when using a Kolmogorov-Smirnov practically impact comparison of distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, assumptions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

As specified here on the [NIST](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm) website, the 3rd assumption for the K-S test is "... the distribution must be fully specified. That is, if location, scale, and shape parameters are estimated from the data, the critical region of the K-S test is no longer valid. It typically must be determined by simulation". With that asumption in place, when would the use of the K-s test be valid? Either you are generating data from a known distribution, in which case you know the distributions are different or else you are using data coming from an unknown distribution which therefore means you have to use data to estimate the location, shape and scale parameters.

Those who came up with the K-S test are much smarter than I so I am obviously misunderstanding something here. What is it that I am possibly misunderstanding that makes this test usable? Is that assummption really weak and just routinely ignored without impact? It just appears to me that the assumption is so rigid as to not have a practical use.

For context and the reason I am trying to understand the test better, I am looking at comparing differences in the distribution of travel distances between two groups. I will try providing appropriate example data soon but wanted the question out there as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-sample K-S test isn't all that useful, partly for the reason you give. It's not *useless*; sometimes you do care about a precise null distribution.  For example, you might want to know if a distribution of $p$-values is $U[0,1]$, or you might be testing a random number generator ([R uses Massart's inequality](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2018/08/01/testing-probability-distribution-generators/), which is basically the one-sample K-S test)

You can fairly easily generate a null distribution by simulation. That's how the Lilliefors test for Normality works: you compute the K-S statistic comparing your data distribution to a Normal with the same mean and variance. The null distribution is generated by taking numbers actually from a Normal distribution and doing the same thing to them.  We work with tables of the Lilliefors test rather than doing simulations each time, but that's because the test was invented back when simulations were slow and difficult.  You could do the same thing for any other parametric family if you wanted to.

Also, you can do a two-sample K-S test, where the null hypothesis is that the two samples are from *the same* distribution, but without specifying the distribution.  This works: similar maths to what gives you the one-sample test gives you the two-sample test.

The other limitation with all of these is that they may have low power against the alternatives you're specifically interested in. Unless you're testing a random number generator, you probably have some idea of important or plausible alternatives, and you would prefer a test that is powerful against those. For example, if you're testing for a power-law distribution, you'd probably want to compare to other well-motivated distributions will long tails, such as exponential or log-Normal, rather than to all possible alternative distributions.